# Numpy: Reshape/horizontally split 3D array into 4D array

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I do have a 3D `np.array` like this:

```
arr3d = np.arange(36).reshape(3, 2, 6)

array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
        [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]],

       [[24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]]])
```

I need to horizontally split every pane of `arr3d` into 3 chunks, such as:

```
np.array(np.hsplit(arr3d[0, :, :], 3))

array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 6,  7]],

       [[ 2,  3],
        [ 8,  9]],

       [[ 4,  5],
        [10, 11]]])
```

This should then lead to a 4D array.

`arr4d[0, :, :, :]` should contain the new splitted 3D array of the first pane of the original 3D array (`np.array(np.hsplit(arr3d[0, :, :], 3))`)

The final result should look like this:

```
result = np.array(
    [
        [[[0, 1], [6, 7]], [[2, 3], [8, 9]], [[4, 5], [10, 11]]],
        [[[12, 13], [18, 19]], [[14, 15], [20, 21]], [[16, 17], [22, 23]]],
        [[[24, 25], [30, 31]], [[26, 27], [32, 33]], [[28, 29], [34, 35]]],
    ]
)

result.shape
(3, 3, 2, 2)

array([[[[ 0,  1],
         [ 6,  7]],

        [[ 2,  3],
         [ 8,  9]],

        [[ 4,  5],
         [10, 11]]],


       [[[12, 13],
         [18, 19]],

        [[14, 15],
         [20, 21]],

        [[16, 17],
         [22, 23]]],


       [[[24, 25],
         [30, 31]],

        [[26, 27],
         [32, 33]],

        [[28, 29],
         [34, 35]]]])
```

I am looking for a pythonic way to perform this reshaping/splitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
sh = arr3d.shape[:-1] + (3, -1)
arr4d = arr3d.reshape(*sh).swapaxes(1, 2)

>>> arr4d
array([[[[ 0,  1],
         [ 6,  7]],

        [[ 2,  3],
         [ 8,  9]],

        [[ 4,  5],
         [10, 11]]],


       [[[12, 13],
         [18, 19]],

        [[14, 15],
         [20, 21]],

        [[16, 17],
         [22, 23]]],


       [[[24, 25],
         [30, 31]],

        [[26, 27],
         [32, 33]],

        [[28, 29],
         [34, 35]]]])
```

**Explanation**

It's the last dimension (in your example, size 6) that you want to split into `(3, -1)`. That's why we first reshape into `(a, b, 3, -1)` (where `(a, b, _)` is the shape of `arr3d`). But since you do a `hsplit()` of each row, then the actual shape you want is `(a, 3, b, -1)`, so we need to swap axes 1 and 2 (more precisely: *roll them*, which we will see below for higher dimensions).

**Another example**

```py
shape = 7, 2, 3*3
arr3d = np.arange(np.prod(shape)).reshape(*shape)
check = np.array([np.array(np.hsplit(arr3d[k], 3)) for k in range(shape[0)])

sh = arr3d.shape[:-1] + (3, -1)
arr4d = arr3d.reshape(*sh).swapaxes(1, 2)
>>> np.equal(arr4d, check).all()
True
```

**Generalization to higher dimensions**

```py
shape = 4, 5, 2, 3*3
ar = np.arange(np.prod(shape)).reshape(*shape)
check = np.array([np.array(np.split(ar[k], 3, axis=-1)) for k in range(shape[0])])

# any dimension
sh = ar.shape[:-1] + (3, -1)
out = np.rollaxis(ar.reshape(*sh), -2, 1)
>>> np.equal(out, check).all()
True
```

Comment: Nice answer. It's not trivial, had to think about it for some time ;-)  Honestly, your ``check = ...`` is more intuitive than using ``reshape/swapaxes``, but probably not as efficient.

Comment: the generalization to `n D --> (n+1) D` was particularly fun...